# Two embedded smooth manifolds of complementary dimensions can be perturbed to intserect in points?

Tags: soft-question, smooth-manifolds

Two embedded smooth manifolds of complementary dimensions can be perturbed to intersect in points?

Let $M$ be an $n$ dimensional manifold and $A,B$ be embedded sub manifolds of dimension $k$ and $n-k$. Is it then true that $A$ and $B$ can we perturbed (what does perturbed mean?) so that $A \cap B$ is a discrete set? Perhaps under some additional hypothesis? Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is true. This notion of "intersecting nicely" is known as [transversality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_(mathematics)).

Comment: Hm. Thank you. I'm still confused as to why submanifolds of complementary dimensions whose intersection is transverse can be perturbed to intersect in isolated points.